# Lags in pose mode

Tags: animation, modifiers, pose-mode

When I try to pose my character in pose mode,Blender gets very slow and lags very badly.The subsurf modifier is displayed in the viewport,but my character is very simple.Is it normal if I get this lag?

Comment: no it's not normal, maybe share your file or at least a part of it: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: ok i will upload it

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, this is a bug/issue with blender >2.8. Since the introduction of OpenSubdiv, the subdivision surface and multires modifiers use a different implementation that, while being GPU capable, runs on the CPU (and there's no way to change it for now), and are very slow even on the high-end machines.

I really don't know about blender's internals. But it looks to me as if blender was re-computing the subsurf modifier every frame instead of working with the subdivided mesh. The order of modifiers does not matter either. If you apply the subdivision modifier, you will get back smooth posing, but then you loose the ability to go back to the low-poly mesh if you need to tweak the topology.

I think this is the official issue link: https://developer.blender.org/T58191